# jsoncpp is having trouble reading my Gson output

Tags: json, gson, jsoncpp

I have a java application that outputs data in Json format (via Gson). I write that data to a file. That file is then read by a C++ application. The C++ application is using jsoncpp to deserialize the json. However, it appears that the C++ application cannot properly deserialize the Json (which is the whole point of using Json).

The problem seems to relate to the class name being included in the Gson output. Gson output sample:

```json
{"nameOfClass":{"fieldName":"fieldvalue","secondFieldName":1}
```

As far as I can tell, "nameOfClass" is throwing off jsoncpp. Perhaps my jsoncpp deserialize method is incorrect? I have specific code to handle the different fields, but nothing that specifically handles that initial class name. Is that something I need to handle?

Comment: This is obviously an illegal JSON instance. How did you produce it so that the dangling property name heads the output document?

Comment: Based on your comment, fluffy, I made an extremely careful look at when the problem showed up. I found that I was serializing the wrong object! I was serializing an object that CONTAINED the object I wanted. So once I got the right object, and serialized THAT one, the problem went away.

Comment: So it sounds like the consuming module simply attempted to consume a JSON with a different (therefore unexpected) structure. But I'm wondering: did you miss the leading `{` in your question?

Comment: Yes, there should have been a leading {

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: user error

Longer answer:
It turns out I was serializing the wrong object. The class of this object CONTAINS a field of type "nameOfClass". What I wanted was that FIELD to be serialized, not the whole object. Because of my inexperience with Json and unfortunate choice of the field's name, I thought the output was malformed. Once I got the field from the object and serialized that, everything was fine.